# How can i find the mule configuration file name in the flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-module-jpa

I want to print the mule configuration file name, in the logger in the flow, how can I get it?

Suppose the configuration file name in test.xml, inside that a flow is having logger, which prints test.xml, how can I get this?

flow name="filenameFlow">
    http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/Hello" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    logger message="#[app.name.toString()]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
/flow>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mule: How to print the file name in logger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200764/mule-how-to-print-the-file-name-in-logger)

Answer (score 0):

TO get the Mule configuration file name which contains your flow, use

## [app.workDir] to extract the M-Config name using substring.

You can also get the running flow name using #[flow.name] in the logger